# Using GCM to make a secure chat application

Tags: android, security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I'm trying to make a chat application using GCM, but I'm a little confused about what the best practices are.

The tutorials I've seen recommend using the XMPP-protocol because you can use existing connections and pass bi-directional messages which makes it faster. The problem is that the GCM payload is limited to 4kb. I wonder whether it's safer to use the push notifications to actually deliver the messages or just to notify the clients that there more messages to download using the HTTP-protocol.

There is also the security problem. I use the OAuth resource owner flow to secure many of HTTP-endpoints. It feels bad to also include the client-id, user-id and access-token/refresh-token in my GCM upstream messages since the payload is already limited. Also, it would require me to write a lot of code ensuring that the access-token has not expired and when to retry and include a refresh-token instead and so on. 
So I wonder if it's better to just send the upstream messages using the HTTP-protocol and then using GCM to notify the receiver to download the message. 
Lastly, I wonder if it's worth using the XMPP-protocol if you are using HTTP for upstream messages anyway. Is the XMPP-protocol still faster, or is it just faster if you are going to use it to send upstream-messages?

Hope I was able to explain my problem well.